# Support for chart drawing in Chart control DEVEXPRESS

Tags: devexpress

VB.Net

I want to be like the picture attached

Picture:

[image: Picture]

Comment: Pleas explain, what you want to do with words. Also include, what you have done, and where exactly is your problem. Than SO might be able to help you.

Comment: I want to change the representation character in the graph with the <  ; I want to be like the picture attached  ; I do not know English neeng confused, expect you sympathy

Comment: Do you want to change only this marker, that you highlighted with the arrow, or all of the markers of line `L-BC`?

Comment: I want to change all of the markers of line L-BC ; Thank you for your support

Comment: Have you reviewed the [How to: Custom Draw Series Points example](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2504)?